# Generate group code between two values of the group with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a big issue , i need to generate a code in the range of two existing columns (CodeFrom / CodeTo)  . Like the following screenshots below :

Input :

[image]

estimated Output :

[image]

Any shared Ideas can help my sure. Thanks

Comment: If it's such a "big" issue, what have you tried so far, and why didn't it work? Images of data don't help us help you either. Take the time to post data as text; it is text after all. DDL and DML statement are received best, but tabular formatted `text` is still far better than an image.

Comment: What is the maximum gap that could be between `CodeFrom` and `CodeTo` as well?

Comment: Where did "8" come from in your desired resultset for Sao Paulo? It started with From = 14 and To = 17 yet you applied some sort of magic in your desires results that changed these values completely.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select codefrom, codeto, town, codefrom as code
      from t
      union all
      select codefrom, codeto, town, code + 1
      from cte
      where code < codeto
     )
select *
from cte;
```

SQL Server has a built-in default recursion limit of 100.  So, if you might be generating more than 100 codes, then add `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

Comment: I would by far recommend a Tally over a rCTE if you're going to end up with more than 10's of rows per Town. They are far faster than a **recursive** Common Table Expression, as they aren't iterative.

Comment: Hi Gordon , thanks for answer. It shows this message in SQL Server : The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion. Sure because of my data size . can i use it this query in view or table ( i tried but not worked)

Comment: This is why I recommend a Tally, @AhmedMJ , they are faster and they don't suffer this problem, as they aren't recursive.

Comment: @AhmedMJ . . . That's what the last paragraph addresses in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned under Gordon's answer in the comments, use a Tally for this. They are far faster by far (especially with larger datasets) and don't suffer the max recursion error as they aren't recursive:

```sql
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3) --1,000 rows, Add more N for more rows
SELECT YT.CodeFrom,
       YT.CodeTo,
       YT.Town,
       T.I AS Code
FROM (VALUES(1,7,'Paris'),
            (14,17,'Sao Paulo'))YT(CodeFrom,CodeTo,Town)
     JOIN Tally T ON YT.CodeFrom <= T.I
                 AND YT.CodeTo >= T.I;
```